# Form generator for inputting URL, description and link

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, form

This is a form generator I created so users can input a URL, description and link. The output will eventually be a JavaScript news slider. The HTML the form generated is irrelevant for now but I'd like to see how I can improve the JavaScript code handing the processing.

This is my first version/draft.

```
<style>

body{
    background-color:green;
}

.hideElement{
display:none;
}

.container{
display: inline-block;
margin:25px;
border: 2px solid white;
padding:10px;

}

p.slidenum{
text-align: center;
font-size: 22px;
font-weight: bolder;
}

p{
font-size: 20px;
}

input[type="text"]{
 background-color:white;
 color:black;
 font-size:16px;
 padding:10px;
}

input[type="button"]{
 background-color:#A17F3F;
 color:white;
 font-size:16px;
 border:2px solid;
 border-radius:5px;
 padding:10px;
}


</style>
```

```
<div id="step1" class=" ">
    <h1>How many slides do you want to generate?</h1>
    <input type="text" id="numOfSlides" name="numOfSlides">
    <input type="button" value="Continue" onClick="generateForm()">
</div>

<div id="step2" class="hideElement">
    <input type="button" id="genCodeButton" value="Generate Code" onClick="generateCode(); hideForm()">
    <input type="button" value="Go Back" onClick="hideStep1(); clearForm(); toggleStep2(); toggleCodeOutput(); showGenCodeButton()">
</div>

<!--empty div, will be populated once user enters num of slides -->
<div id="sliderFormGenerated" class=" "> </div>

<br>
<textarea id="codeOutput" class="hideElement" rows="30" cols="70"></textarea>






<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script>


function generateForm(){
//get num of slides required by user, limit to 8
var numOfSlides = document.getElementById('numOfSlides').value;

//make sure num of slides is a valid integer 1-8
if(isNaN(numOfSlides)){
    alert("Well that doesn't make much sense. Please enter a positive integer 1-8");
    //document.getElementById('sliderFormGenerated').innerHTML="<p>Please enter a positive integer 1-8.</p>";
}
else if (numOfSlides >= 9) {

    alert("The limit is 8 slides, please enter 8 or less.");
    //document.getElementById('sliderFormGenerated').innerHTML="<p>Please enter a positive integer 1-8.</p>";
}
else if(numOfSlides < 1){

    alert("Please enter a positive integer 1-8");
    //document.getElementById('sliderFormGenerated').innerHTML="<p>Please enter a positive integer 1-8.</p>";
}
else {
    //document.getElementById('sliderFormGenerated').innerHTML="<p>Great! For simplicity, let's make one at a time</p>";
    //document.getElementById('sliderFormGenerated').innerHTML=sliderFormNumber;
    //for loop to add unique id to each generated element
    for(var i=0; i < numOfSlides; i++){

        //declare form to be inserted by fucntion call
        var sliderForm = " <p>\"Read More\" URL: </p><input type=\'text\' id=\'link\'>";


        $("#sliderFormGenerated").append("<div class=\"container\"><p class=\"slidenum\">Slide " +(i+1) + "</p><p>Image URL: </p> <input type=\'text\' id=\'imgsrc" + i + "\'" + ">" + i + "<p>Description: </p><input type=\'text\' id=\'description" + i + "\'>" + i +"<p>\"Read More\" URL: </p><input type=\'text\' id=\'link" + i +"\'>" +i + "</div>");

        $('#sliderFormGenerated').removeClass("hideElement");



    }
    toggleStep2(); 
    hideStep1();
}



}

function hideStep1(){
    $('#step1').toggleClass("hideElement");
}

function toggleStep2(){
    $('#step2').toggleClass("hideElement");
}

function showGenCodeButton(){
    $('#genCodeButton').removeClass("hideElement");
}

function hideForm(){
    $('#sliderFormGenerated').addClass("hideElement");
}

function toggleCodeOutput(){
    $('#codeOutput').addClass("hideElement");
}

function clearForm(){
    document.getElementById("sliderFormGenerated").innerHTML=" ";
}

function generateCode(){
    $('#codeOutput').toggleClass("hideElement");
    $('#genCodeButton').addClass("hideElement");

    //TODO: this is the same as numOfSlides variable declared above
    var slides = document.getElementById('numOfSlides').value;

    var inputArray = [];

    for (i = 0; i < slides; i++){

        var temp = document.getElementById('imgsrc' + i).value;
        var temp1 = document.getElementById('description' + i).value;
        var temp2 = document.getElementById('link' + i).value;

        inputArray.push("<img src=\'" + temp + "\'>" + "<p>" + temp1 + "</p>" + "<a href=\'"+temp2+"\'>Read More</a>");


    }


    document.getElementById('codeOutput').innerHTML=inputArray.join('');

}


</script> 
</body>
```

Answer (score 3):

I will start with a snooty remark; please don't submit your first draft, but submit the best code you think you can write.

From a once over:

- You should consider having your JavaScript in a separate file, JavaScript mixed in with your HTML is old skool
- Indentation in `function generateForm(){` is off
- Do not use `alert`, it annoys users, the commented out approach of setting `document.getElementById('sliderFormGenerated').innerHTML` is superior
- Do not keep commented out code
- `" <p>\"Read More\" URL: </p><input type=\'text\' id=\'link\'>";` -> I would prefer

  ```
  ' <p>"Read More" URL: </p><input type="text" id="link">';
  ```
- `onClick="hideStep1(); clearForm(); toggleStep2(); toggleCodeOutput(); showGenCodeButton()"` <-You are lucky I was wearing goggles, this is terrible because

  - You are using `onclick` in the HTML tag -> please use `addEventListener` instead
  - If you had to use `onclick`, then you should at least have grouped these functions into 1 well named function, this way you would not have to create functions like `showGenCodeButton()` which is a short one liner that you only use once.
- This:

  ```
  var temp = document.getElementById('imgsrc' + i).value;
  var temp1 = document.getElementById('description' + i).value;
  var temp2 = document.getElementById('link' + i).value;
  ```

  I am sure you could think up more creative names for those variable names

I have some more items, but at this point I think you need to polish your script and if you wish resubmit it, the quality of this code is very low.